# Iterate within bins of an histogram using EmguCV (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

i have been using EmguCV for some time by now, and it´s quite impressive the things we can do with. And i'm working in one particular project that consist in take one image of an webcam, and compare it with another stored image, and i'm willing achieve that by compare his respectives histograms. And this is going very well but i have this problem making me stuck for quite a while by now, the problem is

---

this code snippet examines the layers of an image and normalizes and applies a threshold on the histogram

```
Image<Gray, Byte>[] channels = webcamFrame.Split();
Image<Gray, Byte> ImgHue = channels[0];

DenseHistogram histo1 = new DenseHistogram(255, new RangeF(0, 255));
histo1.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, byte>[] { ImgHue },false, null);
histo1.Normalize(10);
histo1.Threshold(0.5);
```

How can i iterate the bins of an **DenseHistogram** to compare it with another Histogram?

[image: this code snippet generates this graph]*This Histogram is
 generated by the code above*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to use the [Item property](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.0/document/html/d3a9f67f-f4cc-c543-210e-1e01af36fcc1.htm) of the DenseHistogram.

Comment: Right, but the problem is the version i'm using do not have this property and by the official documentation the way yo retrieve the bins is denseHistogramVariable[index]; but when i try that i'm get this error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: In C# the Item property is accessed using the brackets just like you're doing (denseHistogramVariable[index]; and not denseHistogramVariable.Item[index];). So you're already using it. This doesn't explain why you have an error after that. This can happen if you keep a variable pointing on the data of an image/histogram and use this variable after you disposed of the image/histogram.

Comment: i already have tested make a copy/clone of the variable and the error keeps showing... i just downloaded EMGUcv again (the ".exe" version, i was using the ".zip") and i will reimport all files again in a new project... lets see what happen